# How to use count correctly in sql?

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

I have tow tables 'matches' and 'forum' I need to get match information from the matches table which has comments in the forum table so I use the following query:

```
SELECT distinct forum.match_static_id, matches.* 
from forum 
INNER JOIN matches 
  ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_id 
WHERE forum.comments_yes_or_no = 1
```

I use distinct to avoid getting the same match twice if it has more than one comment in the forum table.

The problem is I want to get the count of each match comments with the same query is it possible? I use :

```
SELECT distinct forum.match_static_id, count(forum.comments), matches.* 
from forum 
INNER JOIN matches 
  ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_i 
WHERE forum.comments_yes_or_no = 1
```

but it give me just one record (which is wrong). What is the problem ?? does I need to use group by ? and if yes where to but it in this crowded query?

Comment: You must be using mysql, right?

Comment: `matches.static_id` is the primary key of `marches`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT forum.match_static_id, count(matches.id), matches.* 
from forum 
INNER JOIN matches 
  ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_i
WHERE forum.comments_yes_or_no = 1
GROUP BY forum.id
```